# Excel 2016 waterfall chart losing data and formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a problem with a report I built and released into the wild.

It contains a waterfall chart with an offset within it linked to a spinner button to change the displayed data range on the fly.  Unfortunately I have to keep fixing the chart as for some reason despite the sheet being protected it is losing all data and formatting and returning to a plain white box that doesn't display or plot anything.  All data ranges and formatting disappear.

There is a person that enters the data on a daily basis, and various people view the spreadsheet as it is for KPIs.  I have been told that the person updating the data and the dashboard date is using Excel 2016 so I am guessing the problem doesn't lie with him?  I am just assuming that anybody viewing the report couldn't break it?  Or if somebody using an older version saved it would that kill off the chart?  Is it a case of enforcing read only permissions aside from myself and the person updating the data?

Has anybody experienced a similar issue?  It is a pain and an inefficient use of my time to keep fixing it!

I have included a before and after for a better idea of what I mean...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the data for the charts? What happens if you try to access it from the chart (right-click -> Select chart data)? Is it still referring to the expected table/range?

Comment: Hey there, nope, the chart ranges have all disappeared.  The named ranges still exist in name manager, but there is no reference to anything in the chart data.